# AUCTeX/RefTeX, the `import` package and cross reference

Tags: cross-referencing, emacs, auctex, import, reftex

Today I switched to the `import` package with the hope that it will simplify the management of the files of my text. It surely did that, but.... It broke `RefTex` in emacs. Now, I cannot lookup my labels using `reftex-reference` (normally bounded to `C-c )`). It doesn't parse the files that were included/imported/added using the `import` package. Thus, I don't get this nice list with all the labels of my whole document.

Is there a way to enjoy both worlds?

### Edit:

I found [this thread](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/auctex/2012-01/msg00001.html) which suggests that this is an open problem... It seems that the problem comes from the way `reftex` parses the document. Adding `import` and `subimport` to the variable `reftex-include-file-commands` cannot solve the problem, since it is documented explicitly that `RefTeX` expects to have the filename right after the command - this is not the case when using `import` package.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way around this problem is to add an `\input` command to your LaTeX file that is commented out. RefTeX will incorporate it into its indexing anyways. For example:

```
\subimport{Chapter1/}{chapter1.tex}
% \input{Chapter1/chapter1.tex}
```

RefTeX finds all the references in `Chapter1/chapter1.tex` now.

A more sophisticated way to deal with this would be to define another LaTeX command, named e.g. `\autoimport`. This command is used like `\input`, but under the hood separates path and filenames and calls `\subimport`. Then add this command's name to `reftex-include-file-commands`.