# AUCTeX/RefTeX with import package in emacs, known problem from 2013 but is there a fix now?

Tags: emacs, auctex, import, reftex

I realized this issue with import in AUCTeX/RefTeX mode today which was also mentioned in the below thread from some years ago:

[AUCTeX/RefTeX, the `import` package and cross reference](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135276/auctex-reftex-the-import-package-and-cross-reference)

RefTeX apparently can not resolve the nice equation/section labels as a list to select from after a <kbd>C-c-)</kbd> if I would like to refer to these labels, which is extremely handy.

Since it has been some time now, I was wondering if this issue was solved with RefTeX or not.

Comment: Can you say how the \keeppath answer is handled in auctex/reftex? That answer is more recent.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the editor recognition of file names used for `\subimport` is hopeless, because the leading portion of the path is implicit. Some different input syntax for `\import` and `\includefrom` might allow the editor to recognize files.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\keeppath[2]{% #1=\input or \include. #2=file path and name
  \begingroup
  \ifx\input#1\relax \def\7{\noexpand\import}\else
  \ifx\include#1\relax \def\7{\noexpand\includefrom}\else
   \def\7{\noexpand#1}\fi\fi % probably should be error
  \filename@parse{#2}% get \filename@area, \filename@base, \filename@ext
  \edef\8{\7{\filename@area}{\filename@base %
      \ifx\relax\filename@ext\else .\filename@ext\fi}}%
  \expandafter\endgroup\8}
```

Then use `\keeppath\input{foo/bar}` instead of `\import{foo/}{bar}` and use `\keeppath\include{foo/bar}` instead of `\includefrom{foo/}{bar}`.

Maybe I should add this alternate syntax to import.sty. Test it well, and if it is good, I will add it.

Comment: I suspect the comand name `\keeppath` is misleading, because it *changes* path!  Maybe `\followpath`?

Comment: I can't tell if your change works LaTeX-wise, but RefTeX understands the notation `\followpath\input{foo/bar}` -- it parses the file path and name given in the argument correctly to grab the `\label`'s and offer them for completion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid the situation hasn't changed since then.